# Woocommerce hidding pages

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to build a multi-vendor affiliate website. I wanted to know how to recognise a user type (f.e. vendor, customer ) while user login's so I can hide some pages from them for example Vendor Dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you started on the right track.

Call `wp_get_current_user()` whose return value will be either one of a `WP_User` object or `null` value. Assuming we have a `WP_User` object, we can inspect the `roles` property found on the object and conditionally check if it matches an allowed role prior to redirecting the user.

```
function redirect_user() {

    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( ! is_null($user) && in_array('vendor', $user->roles) ) {
        //do wp_redirect() or wp_safe_redirect()
    } else {
        //do something else
    }

}

add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_user');
```

You can also use `is_user_logged_in()` as part of your conditional logic to check whether a user is logged in or not - if you prefer.